# How do I create a speed dial button programmatically?

Tags: android

So i've created a simple launcher using [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-custom-launcher-on-android--cms-21358). I've created a few empty buttons that I intend to use to dial a number instantly when they are pressed.

By default, the buttons have no assigned number. I want the button to launch the default contacts application window when first pressed, so the user can select a contact's number to assign to the button. I'll then launch this through an intent.

I have no idea how to make the first part of this work (bringing up the contacts app, and then assigning details to the button). How do I make this work?

Answer (score 1):

if I understand your question corectly you need to start an activity for result . You start your activity (contacts app ) by clicking a button then onActivityResult - > you get the data you want .

For example :

```
private static final int REQUEST_CONTACT = 1;
private static final int RESULT_OK = -1;
private static final int RESULT_CANCELED = 0;
private Uri mInfo;
private Context mContext;

 Button startContactsApp = (Button)findViewByid(...);
        startContactsApp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
               new Thread(new Runnable() { // you need a thread because this operation takes plenty of time
                @Override
                public void run() {
                  Intent contactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
                  contactIntent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE); // to display contacts who have phone number
                  startActivityForResult(contactIntent, REQUEST_CONTACT);
                  }
         }).start();
       }
    });
```

The result:

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_CONTACT){
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){
            mInfo = data.getData();
            String name = getContactNameAgenda();   // the name you need
            String phone = getContactPhoneNumberAgenda();  //the number you need
            Toast.makeText(mContext,"CONTACT ADDED !",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"CANCELLED OR SOME ERROR OCCURRED !",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Here you'll get the name and the phone number from that selected contact :

```
private String getContactNameAgenda(){
    Cursor cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(mInfo, null,
            null, null, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
    cursor.close();
    return name;
}

private String getContactPhoneNumberAgenda(){
    Cursor cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(mInfo, new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts._ID},
            null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
    cursor.close();

    // Using the contact ID now we will get contact phone number
    Cursor cursorPhone = mContext.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER},

            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID + " = ? AND " +  // Phone._ID is for the database ; Phone.CONTACT_ID is for contact when you are not querying that table
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE + " = " +
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE,
            new String[]{id},
            null);

    cursorPhone.moveToFirst();
    String number = cursorPhone.getString(cursorPhone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
    cursorPhone.close();
    return number;
}
```

I hope this will help you.